# Possible to set the height of the textbox of an input type=file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload

Basically I have an `<input type="file" />` that is inside of a div and I would like to make the textbox portion of that input fill the entire div.  Ideally the button part would be outside of the parent div and not clickable.  I have been able to set the width using `size` but I can't seem to set the height.  You can see an example of what i'm talking about here: http://jsfiddle.net/LrpFn/1/

I found some info on styling input type=file, but most of it is related to styling the button.  Is it possible to set the height of the textbox?

My end goal is to create a div where people can drag and drop files, so my plan is to fill this entire div with the text area of the input and then set `opacity` to 0.  I'm open to other suggestions as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using file drop? Does not support old browsers, but does not require any input at all.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do to style a `input[type="file"]`.

However, you can always place a dummy input there (which you can style as you please) and place the correct input positioned over the top, with `opacity: 0` so you can't see it, but clicks on the dummy element activates the correct one.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  The input I want is 300px tall though...  The event that I'm using now is `onchange`, I don't really care about clicks.  Just when the text changes.